# Wordpress, edit text on static homepage

Tags: wordpress

i created a wordpress website for myself, and i have a static page for my home/main site, and a subpage for the blog itself, but i want to edit some texts on my static site via the wordpress text editor under edit pages. But when i try the page in the text editor is empty at start and when i type something in and publish, the page design and previous content gets wiped, only header/footer stay like they were. Is there a specific way i have to display my content to be able to edit it?

```
<div class="bsection">
    <div class="container-fluid content-padding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>some title</h3>
            Text i want to be edited in future
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>some title</h3>
            Text i want to be edited in future
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>some title</h3>
            Text i want to be edited in future
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So yeah i want the text in col-sm-4 to be editable in the wp text editor and keep the css/look of the whole page as it is.

Comment: Do it with shortcodes.

Comment: Can you give me some more info on that please? -I searched and cant seem to find an example that could fit my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `shortcodes`, here's how you can make your own custom shortcodes:

```
function my_container_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'container-fluid content-padding'
    ), $atts );

    return '<div class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '"><div class="row">' 
            . do_shortcode($content) 
            . '</div></div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'my_container', 'my_container_func' );

function my_col_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'col-sm-4',
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts );

    return '<div class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '">'
            . '<h3>' . esc_attr($a['title']) . '</h3>'
            . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_col', 'my_col_func' );
```

In the editor you can use them like this:

```
[my_container]
  [my_col title="My title A"]
    Text content
  [/my_col]
  [my_col title="My title B" class="col-sm-2"]
    Text content
  [/my_col]
[/my_container]
```

For more read the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appertiate it!